# Container comparator uses dummy instance

Tags: c++, std

I stumbled upon a quite subtle thing today. Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
private:
    int id = -1;
public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(int _id) : id(_id) {}

    bool operator() (const MyClass& instance1, const MyClass& instance2) const {
        std::cout << id << std::endl;
        std::cout << instance1.id << std::endl;
        std::cout << instance2.id << std::endl;

        return true;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::set<MyClass, MyClass> classSet;
    classSet.insert(MyClass(1));
    classSet.insert(MyClass(2));

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
-1
2
1
```

As I created all of my class instances using the specialized constructor that sets an `id` value, I was quite surprised that `this->id` evaluates as -1. Apparently C++ creates some dummy instance using the standard constructor.

My questions are:

- Is there some documentation for this behaviour?
- Did I violate some principle like the Rule of Three here, e.g. would having a copy constructor "fixed" the problem (copying one of the instance and thus `this->id` being either 1 or 2)? Or do I always have to prepare my classes for C++ using the standard constructor internally?

Comment: Why are you using the same class for the contents of the set (values) and as a comparison functor (object with overloaded `()` operator)?

Comment: @melpomene: Good advice, thanks. Using a different class would have prevented me from accessing 'this->id' (as it wouldn't exist this way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `std::set<MyClass, MyClass>`, it declares that an instance of the class `MyClass` needs to be used to compare every two instances that the set contains.

If the comparator of `std::set` is default constructible, the set will create an instance to do comparison (for obvious reasons). It will use the default constructor as provided by you, which will set `id` to the the default member initializer you provided.

If you were to remove the default constructor, the program will not build, since `std::set` will require you to *provide* a comparator instance upon initialization of the set object.

Answer (score 4):

Your comparator function is a non-static member function, which means it needs an object to be called on. The [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) creates such an instance since that's what you tild it to do by providing the `MyClass` type as template argument.

My recommendation is to use a non-member `operator<` function overload instead.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    ...

    // the `friend` keyword makes this function a non-member function
    friend bool operator< (const MyClass& instance1, const MyClass& instance2) {
        std::cout << instance1.id << std::endl;
        std::cout << instance2.id << std::endl;

        return instance1.id < instance2.id;
    }
};

...

// No comparator type needed
std::set<MyClass> classSet;
```